# Django's equivalence of ASP.NET UserControl

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

If anyone here is ASP.NET pro, you might know what I mean by user control. I wish to create a similar one in django instead.

So, my problem is that I have several pages in my website, but I need a search bar to appear in every pages. Since I require the views.py to operate this search bar, I cannot do a simple method of

```
{% include 'something.html' %}
```

Therefore, can anyone suggest how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish what you're wanting to do:

[Context Processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

[Template Tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Context Processors can augment the template context with values, regardless of which template is loaded. They are akin to filters in Rails.

Template Tags, like Context Processors, can accomplish anything you can do in Python, but are implemented at the template level.

If you need something to be present on every template, one of the simplest ways to accomplish this is with an inclusion tag, which can also accept values passed to it. An inclusion tag could be implemented at your highest level template, a.k.a your MasterPage, and as long as you don't put it in a block and override it, it would appear on every page that includes that template in its inheritance chain.

If it's just something you want to include on every page, and it doesn't need to do any processing, you should just be able to place the code you want in the top-most template and have subsequent templates inherit that.

I typically have a "base.html" template that all of my templates inherit from. If I need something to be in every page, I put it there. If it's something I want there by default, but want to be able to augment it in subsequent templates, I will place it into a block. That block will let you include or override its default content.

Comment: what if I just need to get a queryset? I am doing this:
tagstring= [definition.encode("utf8") for definition in tag_definitions.objects.values_list('title', flat=True).order_by('title')]

I just need to get it on the template, and I am quite new to django. any example that you can show me?

Comment: For that use case, I would use an inclusion tag. That will let you execute your queryset and hand it to a partial template, which will then be rendered in the template where called.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is kind of old but I just came across it and found a kind-of-solution that works. I call it kind-of-solution because it is a workaround.

I have a few different sites on which I want to display logging information. This display always looks the same (it has the same html) and has the same database table and model class behind it.

My solution/workaround uses the django filters:

1. in views.py I put the list of log-entries in the context

   ```
   context = {'list_log': Log.objects.filter(condition = True) }    
   template = loader.get_template('my_html_file.html')    
   return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
   ```
2. in my_html_file.html I use a custom filter

   ```
   {{ list_log|get_log_uc|safe }}
   ```
3. in the filters.py I load another html file with this custom filter

   ```
   @register.filter
   def get_log_uc(list_log):
       template = loader.get_template('user_control_log.html')
       context = { 'list_log' : log }
       return template.render(context)
   ```
4. in user_control_log.html I have the user control equivalent html

   ```
   {% for log in list_log %}
      <p>log.something</p>
   {% endfor %
   ```